# SQL: Most efficient way to select sequences of rows from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a tagged textual corpus stored in an SQL table like the following:

```
id  tag1 tag2  token  sentence_id                          
0     a    e   five        1
1     b    f  score        1
2     c    g  years        1
3     d    h    ago        1
```

My task is to search the table for sequences of tokens that meet certain criteria, sometimes with gaps between each token.

**For example:**

I want to be able to search for a sequence similar to the following:

- the token has the value `a` in the `tag1` column, and
- the second token is one to two rows away from the first, and has the value `g` in `tag2` or `b` in `tag1`, and
- the third token should be at least three rows away, and has `ago` in the `token` column.

In SQL, this would be something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table t1 
JOIN my_table t2 ON t1.sentence_id = t2.sentence_id 
JOIN my_table t3 ON t3.sentence_id = t1.sentence_id 
WHERE t1.tag1 = 'a' AND (t2.id = t1.id + 1 OR t2.id = t1.id + 2) 
AND (t2.tag2 = 'g' OR t2.tag1 = 'b') 
AND t3.id >= t1.id + 3 AND t3.token = 'ago'
```

So far I have only been able to achieve this by joining the table by itself each time I specify a new token in the sequence (e.g. `JOIN my_table t4`), but with millions of rows this gets quite slow. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I think your question is too generic, you sould limit it to one or two typical queries, and show your solution for this query.

Comment: Moreover: why you use the tags of different DBMSs? You do not use a specific system?

Comment: @Renzo revised, thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Very interesting question. If you have indexes on `tag1`, `tag2` and `token`, you *might* speed things up with subqueries like `(SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE token = 'ago') AS ago` and using your existing join approach (which looks *bona fide* to me) on these.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your question and give more details on how these sequences of tokens work (for instance, what does "each time I specify a new token in the sequence" mean in practice?).

In [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) you can solve this class of queries with a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html). Following your exact specification above:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE
         WHEN lead(tag2, 2) OVER w = 'g' THEN lead(token, 2) OVER w
         WHEN lead(tag1) OVER w = 'b' THEN lead(token) OVER w
         ELSE NULL::text
       END AS next_token
FROM my_table
WHERE tag1 = 'a'
  AND next_token IS NOT NULL
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY sentence_id ORDER BY id);
```

The `lead()` function looks ahead a number of rows (default is 1, when not specified) from the current row in the window frame, in this case all rows with the same `sentence_id` as specified in the partition of the window definition. So, `lead(tag1, 2)` looks at the value of `tag1` two rows ahead to compare against your condition, and `lead(token, 2)` returns the `token` from two rows ahead as column `next_token` *in the current row* and having the same `sentence_id`. If the first `CASE` condition fails, the second is evaluated; if that fails `NULL` is returned. Note that the order of the conditions in the `CASE` clause is significant: different ordering gives different results.

Obviously, if you keep on adding conditions for subsequent tokens the query becomes very complex and you may have to put individual search conditions in separate stored procedures and then call these depending on your requirements.

Comment: Think you *might* need an `AS` between `WINDOW w` and its definition.

Comment: Also think you need `OVER w` in both `THEN` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this staged approach:

1. apply each condition (other than the various distance conditions) as a subquery
2. Calculate the distances between the tokens which meet the conditions
3. Apply all the distance conditions separately.

This *might* improve things, if you have indexes on the `tag1`, `tag2` and `token` columns:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sentence_id FROM
(
  -- 2. Here we calculate the distances
  SELECT cond1.sentence_id,
  (cond2.id - cond1.id) as cond2_distance,
  (cond3.id - cond1.id) as cond3_distance
  FROM
  -- 1. These are all the non-distance conditions
  (
    SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE tag1 = 'a'
  ) cond1
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE 
    (tag1 = 'b' OR tag2 = 'g')
  ) cond2
  ON cond1.sentence_id = cond2.sentence_id
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE token = 'ago'
  ) cond3
  ON cond1.sentence_id = cond3.sentence_id
) conditions
-- 3. Now apply the distance conditions
WHERE cond2_distance BETWEEN 0 AND 2
AND cond3_distance >= 3
ORDER BY sentence_id;
```

If you apply this query to [this SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7087a/3) you get:

```
| sentence_id |
|-------------|
|           1 |
|           4 |
```

Which is what you want. Now whether it's any faster or not, only you (with your million-row database) can really tell, but from the perspective of having to actually *write* these queries, you'll find they're much easier to read, understand and maintain.